# Function needed to convert 2021-08-02T02:11:07.299+0000 to 2021-08-02 02:11:07.299 in Snowflake

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am extracting a timezone through JSON and it is coming in the format 2021-08-02T02:11:07.299+0000. I want to convert the timestamp into a timestamp without "T" in snowflake sql. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use to_timestamp-function and specify the format of your data, with the T in the middle:

```
    select to_timestamp('2021-08-02T02:11:07.299+0000','YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF3+TZHTZM');
```

References to documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions